# Apply an XSL Transform to an XML REST result without being able to specify the XSL file path in the XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a simple XSLT file that I would like to apply to an XML file retrieved in browser to convert it to HTML and make it nicely presented. However I am unable to modify the xml before hand to specify the XSL style.

Is there a way I can force the XSL to be applied to the XML file without being able to the specify the XSL style on the source file itself?

Do I need some kind of 'proxy' html file to host the source url and transform? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Building a GUI from REST is not so simple. The client state is usually a combination of different resource representation, so in order to create a HTML file, you have to transform not just, but many XML-s. Ofc if you want to have a real webApp, and not just a CRUD like interface. You can do the transformations in the browser with javascript, or in a server side REST client with any server side language. I fail to see how choosing the proper XSL file can be a problem by any of those languages...

Comment: In this case the REST call I am making returns a single XML result that I want to make presentable. XSL should provide the easiest way to do this but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

in Java, you would parse the XML into a `org.w3c.dom.Document` object.   Construct `javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource` object on this.  Construct a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` for the XSLT file.  Call the `transform` method on the transformer object, passing the DOMSource to it.  The output will be the transformed result.

Comment: I'm really looking for an solution that doesn't require the use of Java.